# Matlab script build compilation doesn't start

Tags: matlab, build, compilation

I pray you have a good day. :-)

After two months I finally finished my "program" in MatLab. It computes recumbent bike's strain ans deformation analyticaly. But it's in form of a script.

When I start my

```
Start.m
```

Matlab command window will show me menu:

- http://imgur.com/Nxr1VS7 ~ menu

I choose from options and input 1 / 2 numbers per question.

Then it will do the computation with results:

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJXTF.jpg ~ Text results
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/BjEv5.jpg ~ Graph results

I want it to be executable in any machine without MatLab so I start the

```
 deploytool ~ command
```

where I choose

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/BpiVj.jpg ~ Deployment Project

Then I pick up my Start.m file and press Built

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/LxQ7e.jpg ~ Files to Built

The full Built window log is like this:

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/kmj4i.jpg ~ Built Log

I even putted there MCR installer and installed it, but when I start my .exe file, my computer "works for a while" ans in task manager I have Lehokolo.exe (using system resources for 20% CPU), but after aprox 30seconds, it will calm down and nothing happens...

MCR installs: Matlab Compiler Runtime 8.0

and before that it installs Visual C++ (64bit)

I tried it wih my frieds notebook but it won't work either. (Installed MCR + tried start my program)

**My thoughts:**

- Deploytool can create .exe file only if I have GUI, not only a script.
- I tried installing Windows SDK from this site: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279 and one of threads here on mathworks.com said that it has to be installed -before- Matlab, so maybe I have to reinstall it.
- If I type mbuild -setup and locate the compilers, the response is: *No supported SDK or compiler was found on this computer. For a list of supported compilers, see http://www.mathworks.com/support/compilers/R2012b/win64.html* Even though I installed the Windows SDK today again. With Visual C++ 2010 too. "No supported sdk compiler..."

I tried it on another machine with Matlab 2012b too and with the same result. 40seconds of "work" and then nothing.

Thanks for any response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should chose "Standalone Application", not "Windows Standalone Application" in your project type if you want to build a CLI app. [This](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2010/11/18/deploying-standalone-applications/) may give you further hints.

**Later edit:** Don't worry, even if the programs starts in CLI, it will be able to create figures, plots and so on. The only drawback is that it will run "all the time" (its execution is not natively event-driven as an application launched within a GUI).

Comment: If you mean: http://imgur.com/4d9GwmX
I tried it and the result is better! After some "work" it finally shows my menu: http://imgur.com/FeKnxWI

Comment: Oh, I meant "Console application"... the options in your drop down list are different than in mine. Sorry! :-)

Comment: Edit2:

If you mean: [link](http://imgur.com/4d9GwmX)

I tried it [link](http://imgur.com/1sBXFoT) and the result is better! After some "work" it finally shows my menu: [link](http://imgur.com/FeKnxWI)

Which works, so superb! But when I put there some beginning variables, it ends with error: [Link](http://imgur.com/pe7AMR7)

It's (I think?) about "my made function" Dangle (D as "The" Angle) which computes an angle within three points in 2D-system, in more detail here: [link](http://imgur.com/0faCBJF)

I'm not sure what about it. Change it to AlphaR = sym('AlphaR') maybe? I'll try it.

Comment: Looks like in your function `Dangle` tries call to `syms` on line 10, but it doesn't know where to take it from. If is defined by you, remember to put its folder in your Matlab path before building the app, for it to be accessible for compiling.

Comment: Ah. So not fair.... I really wanted to compile "external application". Sym/Syms function is normal in matlab: :[link](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/creating-symbolic-variables-and-expressions.html): but as I read some threats, I found this: :[link](http://www.mathworks.com/products/compiler/supported/compiler_support.html): So Compiling Symbolic Toolbox is not supported.... :-( Can't compile and I'm affraid the GUI won't work either... || THANKS for your help though, I learned something new thanks to you :-)

Comment: Always glad to help. Sorry for the negative result though.